# Cannot launch expo standalone .apk despite successful build

Tags: react-native, expo

I can't test my app in production on my android physical device nor the emulator.

When i launch my app. i get the following error

```
java.io.EOFException
```

My app build successfully but i got some errors in the logs yet.

```
[stderr] Unable to get progress logger. Download progress will not be displayed.
:ReactAndroid:prepareBoost
:ReactAndroid:downloadDoubleConversion
[stderr] Unable to get progress logger. Download progress will not be displayed.
:ReactAndroid:prepareDoubleConversion
:ReactAndroid:downloadFolly
[stderr] Unable to get progress logger. Download progress will not be displayed.
:ReactAndroid:prepareFolly
:ReactAndroid:downloadGlog
[stderr] Unable to get progress logger. Download progress will not be displayed.
:ReactAndroid:prepareGlog
:ReactAndroid:downloadJSCHeaders
[stderr] Unable to get progress logger. Download progress will not be displayed.
[stderr] Unable to get progress logger. Download progress will not be displayed.
[stderr] Unable to get progress logger. Download progress will not be displayed.
[stderr] Unable to get progress logger. Download progress will not be displayed.
[stderr] Unable to get progress logger. Download progress will not be displayed.
[stderr] Unable to get progress logger. Download progress will not be displayed.
[stderr] Unable to get progress logger. Download progress will not be displayed.
[stderr] Unable to get progress logger. Download progress will not be displayed.





[stderr] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[stderr] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[stderr] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[stderr] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.





[stderr] warning: Attempt to recreate a file for type com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.config.ExponentKernel$Database
[stderr] warning: Attempt to recreate a file for type com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.config.ExponentKernel$Database
[stderr] warning: File for type 'com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.config.GeneratedDatabaseHolder' created in the last round will not be subject to annotation processing.
[stderr] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[stderr] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[stderr] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[stderr] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[stderr] 3 warnings





[stderr] /src/exponent/android-shell-app/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/dialog/AlertFragment.java:37: Error: Avoid non-default constructors in fragments: use a default constructor plus Fragment#setArguments(Bundle) instead [ValidFragment]
[stderr]   public AlertFragment(@Nullable DialogModule.AlertFragmentListener listener, Bundle arguments) {
[stderr]          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[stderr] /src/exponent/android-shell-app/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/dialog/SupportAlertFragment.java:30: Error: Avoid non-default constructors in fragments: use a default constructor plus Fragment#setArguments(Bundle) instead [ValidFragment]
[stderr]   public SupportAlertFragment(@Nullable DialogModule.AlertFragmentListener listener, Bundle arguments) {
[stderr]          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[stderr]    Explanation for issues of type "ValidFragment":
[stderr]    From the Fragment documentation:
[stderr]    Every fragment must have an empty constructor, so it can be instantiated
[stderr]    when restoring its activity's state. It is strongly recommended that
[stderr]    subclasses do not have other constructors with parameters, since these
[stderr]    constructors will not be called when the fragment is re-instantiated;
[stderr]    instead, arguments can be supplied by the caller with setArguments(Bundle)
[stderr]    and later retrieved by the Fragment with getArguments().
[stderr]    http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Fragment()
[stderr] 2 errors, 0 warnings
```

I'am very confused i don't know how to deal with this. My app work pretty well in development.

Any help ?